# Issues building the libffi gem native extension when trying to install Jekyll on macOS Catalina

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, macos-catalina, libffi

EDIT: I wrote up a more detailed solution on my blog [here](https://dylanamartin.com/2020/03/22/installing-jekyll-and-its-toolchain-on-mac-os-catalina.html) if you want to walk through all the steps.

I'm trying to install Jekyll via `gem install Jekyll` on macOS Catalina using Ruby install via homebrew and located at `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby` and I'm running into the following error

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/foobar/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
/Users/foobar/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181118-49440-k8mjki.rb
extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory:
/Users/foobar/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/Users/foobar/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
Running autoreconf for libffi
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4 --output=aclocal.m4t
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at
/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
make: ***
["/Users/foobar/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-darwin18"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a]
Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/foobar/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/foobar/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0-static/ffi-1.9.21/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

I've already tried updating my Xcode Command Line tools via `xcode-select --install` but I got back the following message:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Does anyone know how I can build `libffi` on my machine so that I Jekyll can use it as a dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaaaaand I figured it out!  Credit to @ffleming [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/65069406-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-on-macos-high-sierra).  Here's what you need to do:

1. reinstall libffi on brew using `brew reinstall libffi`
2. add the new brew-installed libffi flags to your shell instance, e.g.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

3. Run `gem install jekyll` and you should be sorted!